# String-join() function is affected by order of XML structure (Nodes)

Tags: string, xpath, xslt, concatenation, saxon

I normally use String-join() functions extensively for handling and joining values coming from Database, however currently I observed if the second variable of the function is first fetched/present in the XSL/XML structure than the first variable, then the output is reversed of that expected value.
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">  
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>  
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:variable name="b"> 
      <row> 
        <value>2</value> 
      </row> 
    </xsl:variable>  
    <xsl:variable name="a"> 
      <row> 
        <value>1</value> 
      </row> 
    </xsl:variable>  
    <xsl:variable name="c"> 
      <row> 
        <value>1</value> 
      </row> 
    </xsl:variable>  
    <xsl:variable name="d"> 
      <row> 
        <value>2</value> 
      </row> 
    </xsl:variable>  
    <!-- Version a-->  
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(($a,$b)[. != '']/row/value/text(), ';')"/>  
    <!-- OP - 2;1 -->  
    <!-- Version b-->  
    <xsl:value-of select="formatter:crlf()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(($c,$d)[. != '']/row/value/text(), ';')"/>
    <!-- OP - 1;2 -->  
    <!-- Version c-->    
    <xsl:value-of select="formatter:crlf()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(($a[. != '']/row/value/text(),$b[. != '']/row/value/text()), ';')"/> 
    <!-- OP - 1;2 -->  
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here, I have four variables a, b, c, d with values 1, 2, 1, 2 respectively and 3 versions of string-join() function.
With the first version a I get output 2;1 which is not what I was expecting and it seems since b was declared before a, when fetching the value, b was fetched earlier and in that order it was joined and printed.
With version b, I get the expected since c is declared before d.
With version c, I did a tweak and was now able to get the correct sequence.

My expectation is that this should NOT happen. In real production scenarios I have many values coming from DBs which are fetched asynchronously and when needed so when I perform string-join() operation I expect the correct output.

I verified this is not due to SAXON or XPATH issue, since I tried both SAXON 10 with XPATH 3 & SAXON 9 with XPATH 2 and was getting the same result.

Let me know what you guys think and what can I do?

- Note: I cannot change the string-join() function since that brutally affects production environment variables in many different places.

Comment: FWIW, I get the result of `1;2` with your "version a" and a result of `2;1` with `string-join(($b,$a)/row/value/text(), ';')`. Using Saxon 10.6 HE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `/` operator which sorts nodes in document order so in `string-join(($a,$b)[. != '']/row/value/text(), ';')`, while you define an order `$a,$b`, the use of `/row/value/text()` ensures that document order is used, only that I think document order for nodes from different documents is basically undefined.

You can use `!` instead of `/` e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="string-join(($a,$b)[. != '']!row!value!text(), ';')"/>`.

See [example online for Saxon HE 11](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet+xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22+xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22+version%3D%223.0%22%3E++%0A++%3Cxsl%3Aoutput+method%3D%22text%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%2F%3E++%0A++%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22%2F%22%3E+%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22b%22%3E+%0A++++++%3Crow%3E+%0A++++++++%3Cvalue%3E2%3C%2Fvalue%3E+%0A++++++%3C%2Frow%3E+%0A++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E++%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22a%22%3E+%0A++++++%3Crow%3E+%0A++++++++%3Cvalue%3E1%3C%2Fvalue%3E+%0A++++++%3C%2Frow%3E+%0A++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E++%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22c%22%3E+%0A++++++%3Crow%3E+%0A++++++++%3Cvalue%3E1%3C%2Fvalue%3E+%0A++++++%3C%2Frow%3E+%0A++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E++%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22d%22%3E+%0A++++++%3Crow%3E+%0A++++++++%3Cvalue%3E2%3C%2Fvalue%3E+%0A++++++%3C%2Frow%3E+%0A++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E++%0A++++%3C%21--+Version+a--%3E++%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22string-join%28%28%24a%2C%24b%29%5B.+%21%3D+%27%27%5D%21row%21value%21text%28%29%2C+%27%3B%27%29%22%2F%3E+%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3Croot%2F%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML) and [for Saxon HE(C) 12](https://saxonc-xmlworkbench.azurewebsites.net/?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet+xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22+xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22+version%3D%223.0%22%3E++%0A++%3Cxsl%3Aoutput+method%3D%22text%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%2F%3E++%0A++%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E+%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22b%22%3E+%0A++++++%3Crow%3E+%0A++++++++%3Cvalue%3E2%3C%2Fvalue%3E+%0A++++++%3C%2Frow%3E+%0A++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E++%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22a%22%3E+%0A++++++%3Crow%3E+%0A++++++++%3Cvalue%3E1%3C%2Fvalue%3E+%0A++++++%3C%2Frow%3E+%0A++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E++%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22c%22%3E+%0A++++++%3Crow%3E+%0A++++++++%3Cvalue%3E1%3C%2Fvalue%3E+%0A++++++%3C%2Frow%3E+%0A++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E++%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22d%22%3E+%0A++++++%3Crow%3E+%0A++++++++%3Cvalue%3E2%3C%2Fvalue%3E+%0A++++++%3C%2Frow%3E+%0A++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E++%0A++++%3C%21--+Version+a--%3E++%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22string-join%28%28%24a%2C%24b%29%5B.+%21%3D+%27%27%5D%21row%21value%21text%28%29%2C+%27%3B%27%29%22%2F%3E+%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%0A&code-type=XSLT&input-type=None).

Comment: I’ve never seen the map operator used like this. I’ll have to remember that you can use it similar to the path operator. Very handy! I might go read more about it in the spec too.  I don’t use it enough to know all of the details. Thanks for the inspiration Martin!

Comment: The use of "/" is so well-established that it doesn't occur to people that "!" is a simpler operator that usually does what you want with less effort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DanielHaley, it worked perfectly in my system with SAXON 10.6 XSLT 3.0. Just for the sake of more info: is this possible without changing the string-join() function?

Comment: @SiddhantK. - This is actually Martin’s answer. I don’t think your issue can be solved without changing the string-join() (for the reasons given in the answer). Also, I don’t think removing the examples from the answer improves the answer. It will most likely help future visitors to this answer.